# ASP NetCore 8 + JWT with key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-8

Previously I was developing several applications in Asp Net Core 6, one of them is responsible for generating tokens (jwt) that are then used to authenticate against other applications.

The problem arose when creating a new application, but this time in asp net core 8. It is not possible to authenticate it. Any request returns 401.

Token generator:

```
public TokenDTO GetToken(string id)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, id),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    };

    var roles = _aplicacionRepository.ObtenerPermisos(id);
    foreach (var rol in roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, rol.Codigo));
    }

    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_settings.Value.Key);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _settings.Value.Issuer,
        audience: _settings.Value.Audience,
        claims: claims.ToArray(),
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_settings.Value.TokenExpirationMinutes),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
    );

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    return new TokenDTO()
    {
        access_token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
        expires_in = _settings.Value.TokenExpirationMinutes * 60,
        token_type = "bearer"
    };
}
```

New asp net core 8:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(def =>
  {
      def.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = Authenticators.Application;
      def.DefaultChallengeScheme = Authenticators.Application;
      def.DefaultScheme = Authenticators.Application;
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(Authenticators.Application, o =>
  {
      o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidIssuer = configuration["Security:Issuer"],
          ValidAudience = configuration["Security:Audience"],
          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Security:Key"])),
          ValidateIssuer = true,
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
      };
  })
```

The error I get in the response is:

> Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature is invalid"

The truth is that I don't know what to try anymore, I can't find documentation about it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title summarizes the problem you are having or the question you have. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: Many systems have moved from Windows Authentication to OAUTH2 authentication.  Does code still run with Core 6?  Need to find out if the issue is with the type of authentication or the transition from Core 6 to Core 8.  Did you try Core 7?  There are lots of bugs still left to fix in Core 8.

Comment: We have mini-applications that are like small services (not micro), approximately 9 of them are in net.6, the last one is in net.8. The others work correctly. Net 7 I didn't try

Comment: Do you have a [mre] you can post somewhere?

Comment: Could you pls decode your token to check if it is correct or not comparing with two different version application. You could decode it on site [here](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: My token is correct because if I try it in another application it works correctly. They have all the same secrets

Comment: We found the problem. The key was generated in 512 encryption but the key was 256. So net 8's jwt validates that those things match. We adjusted the generation to 256 and the problem was solved.